# Is Ubuntu a globally developed software product?

Tags: history-of-ubuntu

I want to know if all versions of Ubuntu can be considered as a globally developed software product i.e. if developers from multiple countries/continents contribute to the Ubuntu OS. If so, is there a concrete reference I can point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, Ubuntu is widely developed, many countries and developers contribure. Look at: [Community](http://community.ubuntu.com/?_ga=1.116888325.289612486.1469466602) ,[Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/) and [Contribute](http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/) For more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

You can read [About Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu) for more information.